# How do i select an element which doesn't have any value in text property and has same className, same Id in Appium Automation?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I am automating e-commerce app, and i need to select one category of shopping. The issue is all category have same className, id and without value in text property.

[image: screenshot]

I have tried like this..

```
driver.findElementsById("//com.app.mobileapp:id/imgCategory").get(1).click();
```

I get `Index out of bound` Exception.

Thanks

Suresh;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below Xpath. I have doubt on index you are using in `get()` function.

```
By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[@index='2']");
```